# Ruby on Rails Refer System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to implement OLA and UBER like referral system. I have an User Table, Account Referral Table and I am adding Gifts from backend. I do not understand how to use association. Please guide me through.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You have to show us where you are stuck by joining code or something more concrete then 'I do not understand how to use association'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first generate a migration to change the database for your association

```
rails g migration AddFieldToTable
```

Example:

```
class AddUserToRef < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
add_reference :refs, :user, index: true
end
end
```

then in the controller when you create a ref you need to add:

```
ref.user_id = user.id
```

And then if you want to search for refs by user all you need to do is:

```
ref = Refs.where('user_id = ?' , user.id)
```

This is how i do things. But you can use :has_many and :belongs to as well

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Here's the info about that.

Enjoy

**EDIT**

Example for cash:

Ref.create:

```
receiver = User.find(params[:receiver])
giver = current_user
ref.receiver = receiver.id
ref.giver = current_user.id
if ref.save
receiver.update_attribute(:cash, receiver.cash.to_i + 150)
giver.update_attribute(:cash, giver.cash.to_i + 150)
end
```

Comment: Thanks..but I want model structure for code referring and give some cashback or gift to referrer and referral.

Comment: all you need to do is create the connections man.... I'll put example for cashback

Comment: I am generating gifts from my backend and an user has many referral but only one referrer.

Comment: So, I need model structure with association